# Mutating a mutable prop directly the computed set handler were not called

Tags: vue.js

Reproduction link

https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-kirch-ss507?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I change the prop but the set handler were not called, something I am ignored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating `test` property of `dTest` - but your setter is defined on `dTest` as a whole and not on its key `test`.

If you want your setter to be called - you should mutate the `test` computed property:

```html
<div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" :test.sync="test"/>
  </div>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
      {{ test.test }}
      <button @click="change">click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: ['test'],

  methods: {
    change() {
        // this.test = '.python'
        this.$emit('update:test',{test: this.test.test.concat([1])});
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to asked is the props on Vue are not change directly in children componts，but I do this and the setter is not called. https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-kirch-ss507?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The setter will be only called if you assign to it - but not if you are assigning to its `properties` - and `test` is a property of `test`.